# get real time data from api in flutter app

Tags: flutter

I have an API that is related to digital currency rates
How can it be displayed in real time?  I want the data to be displayed whenever the exchange rate changes.

I would like to use a timer that requests every 1 second.
Thankful

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this: **apiCallFunction** will be your API request.

```
import 'dart:async';
void main(){
  const oneSec = Duration(seconds:1);
  Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) => apiCallFunction());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get real-time data and update from API, you must use "web socket API", which you can get from the backend developer who made the API